# Wikipedia - to - Facebook linked data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, wikipedia, semantic-web

I'm trying to include facebook pages in a linked-data application,

like, the page:

[facebook.com/pages/Friendship/105625816137032](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Friendship/105625816137032)

connects to:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship)

without ambiguity,

is there a "**105625816137032**" => "**Friendship**" dataset somewhere?
or a method that isn't *screen-scraping facebook*?

it seems crazy that facebook would intentionally try to avoid these sort of links, if that's what's happening, or I am just missing them.

thanks!

Comment: Where, in FB or in WP? Wikipedia has no id field with "105625816137032".

Comment: ya i reckon that facebook has an id field with "Friendship".

Ideally the data could be written into Freebase/Dbpedia/sameas.org like other awesome resources have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pre-compiled resources mapping Facebook ids with dbpedia ids - it woudl certainly be a very nice project. There are a few options:

1.) Asking Facebook nicely - you'd never know... Ultimately, it should benefit everybody.

2.) Scraping Facebook - the ethics are probably sketchy, and lots of interesting pages aren't linked to wikipedia. eg. http://www.facebook.com/PulpFiction

3.) Guessing eg. Wikipedizing the name - eg. putting in underscores for spaces

The resulting mapping set could be tested by comparing the types of the matches (i think that the mappings would have to be done manaully, and probably aren't too much use)

Facebook don't seem to have put too much thought into the graph - the data is all pretty unstructured and difficult to work with as far as I can see.